# Python-Selenium scroll until certain text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to have selenium scroll facebook page until certain text then get the HTML tags from that page. I'm trying to facebook post date text and have Seleinum scroll until that page. This code doesn't throw me error but doesn't does the task either. How can I achieve this? Right now it keeps scrolling and doesn't stop.
I'm just trying to scroll the page until the text 'Oct 5th' is visible.

```
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/search/latest/?q=%23blacklivesmatter")
sleep(4)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Oct 5th')]")))
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: We need to look for the presence of an element instead of visibility.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/search/latest/?q=%23blacklivesmatter")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

find_elem = None
scroll_from = 0
scroll_limit = 3000
while not find_elem:
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(%d, %d);" %(scroll_from, scroll_from+scroll_limit))
    scroll_from += scroll_limit
    try:
        find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Oct 5th')]")))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
driver.close()
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Instead of Oct 5th I just used 50 mins as an example. It didn't scroll down to where I wanted it to. It just stops. I'm pretty much trying to scroll down to certain facebook post time.

Comment: @Dilli What if you removed the `try` and `except` block?

Comment: I edited my answer a little. Does it even scroll once?

Comment: That doesn't work either. Does exactly what it did before :/

Comment: It does scroll down until certain amount then the script stops.

Comment: Okay I am trying for a different URL right now. See if it works. Let me get back to you in 10 mins

Comment: Thank you. Also maybe we can pass in the elements along with something like if this element has this text then set it to true. So that way I'm only looking for 'time' and not other relevant text in the webpage?

Comment: Okay. I updated the answer to check presence of an element on the webpage.

Comment: Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/n5/ld2x170j2plfn3rlsf1p_dqw0000gr/T/tmpBKOjHt/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10659)
It throws me error.

Comment: Did you set the webdriver to `Firefox` instead of `Chrome`? Also update you pip package for selenium

Comment: I've been using firefox since the beginning

Comment: Did you update selenium? Also I added the `try-except` block to the code again.

Comment: Hey. I'll let you know the outcome when I get the chance!

Comment: @Dilli were you able to take a look at it?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help! I'm having a little issue at the momment. I'm trying to pass in the contains text as input data like this. Doesn't seem to be working
find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '%s')]"))) % inputDate

Also. Could you please show me how I can make sure that it's inspecting the text from certain element and not the whole page? I've provided element in the main thread!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this text you are looking for is **somewhere** on the page, even if it is not immediately visible, it should still be visible in the HTML directly, without the need to scroll. The scrolling is only required when the page needs to be refreshed to load additional content that was not available before.

Now, I would suggest changing the following in your approach:

1. First of all, if the page does require to load some data that was unavailable before the scroll, you should give it enough time to do so. If you scroll and look for the text too quickly, it won't have enough time to get the updated HTML and you will basically just query the same DOM each time. Now given that you don't necessarily know when your text will appear, you will have to wait for a constant hard coded period each time. Few seconds should be enough, at least initially just to proved that it works.
2. Just to exclude possible issues with using `wait.until`, try looking for this text directly in the HTML source. You can change it later and use `wait.until` when you ensure that the rest of your script works properly.

Comment: We do need to scroll as I'm trying to get additional posts. For instance I'm looking for the text "50 mins" which is only shown after the page has been loaded by scrolling down.

Comment: @Dilli ok, then follow the suggestions in my answer